# Select single object and it's corresponding list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, class, lambda

I have a class which contains `ProjectID` and its detail as follows and I would like to retrieve the list detail from the SQL server. I am struggling to convert list of rows into `ProjectModel`.
I have tried below and referred various source but no luck. I want to write code for get list instead of **BuildAutoCompleteList(PTO)**.

Should i need to use `groupby` to achieve the result.

**Class**

```
public class ProjectModel
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SegmentModel> Segments { get; set; }        
}

public class SegmentModel
{
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }        
    public string MileStone { get; set; }        
}
public class ProjectMilestone
{
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public string MileStone { get; set; }
    public ProjectMilestone() { }
}
```

**Entity**

```
var collection = _db.GetReportMilestones().Join(_db.GetReports(), RM => RM.ReportId, R => R.Id,
                (RM, R) => new { RM, R }).
                Join(_db.GetProjects(), P => P.R.ProjectId, PR => PR.Id, (P, PR) => new { P, PR }).Where(M => M.P.R.StateId == 1)
                .Select(PTO => new ProjectTimelineModel
                {
                    ProjectName = PTO.PR.Name,
                    ProjectID = PTO.PR.Id,
                    Segments = BuildAutoCompleteList(PTO)
                }).ToList();
```

Below is my attempt, which throws the error.

```
 var collection = _db.GetReportMilestones().Join(_db.GetReports(), RM => RM.ReportId, R => R.Id,
            (RM, R) => new { RM, R }).
            Join(_db.GetProjects(), P => P.R.ProjectId, PR => PR.Id, (P, PR) => new { P, PR }).Where(M => M.P.R.StateId == 1)
            .Select(PTO => new ProjectMilestone
            {
                ProjectName = PTO.PR.Name,
                ProjectID = PTO.PR.Id,
                StartDate = PTO.P.RM.ScheduledDate,
                EndDate = PTO.P.RM.PassedDate,
                MileStone = PTO.P.RM.Name
            }).ToList();

        var results = collection.OrderBy(n => n.ProjectName);

        var groupbyResult = results.GroupBy(n => new { n.ProjectID, n.ProjectName }).Select(x => new ProjectTimelineModel()
        {
            ProjectID = x.Key.ProjectID,
            ProjectName = x.Key.ProjectName,
            Segments = x.GroupBy(n => n.ProjectID)

        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Are you trying to return a single `ProjectModel` with a list of its child `Segments` or a list of `ProjectModel`?

Comment: list of `ProjectModel` with `Segments` list

Comment: What is the error? What is `ProjectTimelineModel`?